# MVC4 - JQueryUI Html Helper for a slider is rendering but isn't visible

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm using [jQuery UI Helpers](http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/GettingStarted) in my MVC4 application:

```
<div class="span6">
    @Html.JQueryUI().SliderFor(x => x.WantsStudentWeighting).Min(1).Max(10)
</div>
```

When I run my application, the slider is there but it's not 100% visible. I know it's there because I can see the slider handle when I click in and around the area the slider's in and move it along the scale - value of Weighting also changes too. Here's proof:

[image]

All my scripts and css files are there. I've tried to edit the jqueryui.slider.css file but to no avail. I've also changed background colour of containing DIV to make sure the slider wasn't being rendered in white.

I've run out of ideas - some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see what class is hiding it?

Comment: Do you mean is one css style overriding another? I could inspect the element in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

In the BundleConfig file create a new bundle for the jquery-ui.unobtrusive-x.y.z.js. It is also possible to add this to the jQuery UI bundle so it will always be included when jQuery UI is referenced. The following example demonstrates this.

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-{version}.js"));
```

Render the bundles on the layout page or the views that need them. Add the jQuery UI CSS files like so:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

And the JavaScript files:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

The bundles will handle the version number automatically so you do not have to worry about them when upgrading packages.

If you use client side validation include the validation scripts before the jQuery UI Helpers script. [More info.](http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/Datepicker#format-validation)

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

I hope this help